# css transitions with change in transition property during transition

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a css transition which runs for say 5 seconds on a property. If I remove the transition within this duration(sat after 2 sec) through script by changing class to `cls2`, will it affect the running transition or will it run to completion ?

```
.cls1 {
transition : background-color 5s ease-in
}

.cls2 {
  /*transition : background-color 5s ease-in*/
}
```

Comment: have you tried to find out yourself ?

Comment: I have and to me it appears that it does not complete to end. But I am looking for reason of this behaviour and if its mentioned in the specification or it is browser specific.

Comment: Did you remove the class where the transition is declared or did you reset the transition to 0 .It makes a big difference, since property cannot be removed but reset.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I toggled to a class which doesn't have that transition.

Comment: Okay, removing the class  also removes the transition-duration, and sets it back to default value (0). If you add another class with a different duration, it will reset it and restart it. You probably want an animation while you could stop it and resart it (animation-play-state:running/paused) .  look at this article https://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/ , you might find what you need  at  https://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/#obtaining-the-current-keyvalue-percentage

Answer (score 1):

Easy enough to test:

```js
document.body.style.setProperty('--bg-color', 'red');

function changeColor() {
  const varName = '--bg-color';
  const colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo'];
  const body = document.querySelector('body');
  const currentColor = body.style.getPropertyValue(varName)
  const currentColorIndex = colors.findIndex((color) => color === currentColor);
  body.style.setProperty(varName, colors[currentColorIndex + 1 % colors.length]);
}

function changeClass() {
  const target = document.querySelector('#target');
  target.classList.toggle("cls1");
}
```

```css
.cls1 {
  transition : background-color 5s ease-in
}
```

```html
<div id="target" class="cls1" style="height: 100vh; width: 100vw; background: var(--bg-color)">
<button onclick="changeColor()">Change Color</button>
<button onclick="changeClass()">Change Class</button>
</div>
```

So, if we remove the transition midway through the transition, the transition abruptly stops and we just get the new background color.  This makes sense-- the element no longer has any transition property set.

Comment: Is this behaviour guaranteed since we are combing css with js here ?

Comment: @user2599052 - how were you intending on toggling classes and changing background colors without JS?  CSS hovers, perhaps?  I could probably quickly create a second snippet that verifies that, but I imagine the effect will be the same, because ultimately the result is the removal of the transition property...

Comment: With js only. But is this going to be consistent

Comment: I can think of no reason it would not be.